# How to add emojis in the code for automating with PYAUTOGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pyautogui
import os
import emoji
text = emoji.emojize(":thumbs_up:")
Time = input("Enter your time here:")
while(True):
    present = datetime.now()
    present = present.strftime("%H:%M")
    if (present == Time):
        pyautogui.write(text , interval=0.25)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(2)
        break
```

Can anyone help me how to make pyautogui type emojis too?
im a beginner....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it cant because it is available only by **windows key+. (dot key)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```py
pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "ALT CODE HERE")
```

and place alt code of emoji in the "ALT CODE HERE" section